# T_OBJECT_OPERATOR while trying to insert data into mySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

trying to input code into the sqldatabase...what am i missing in here?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

```
<?php
$name = "";
$email = "";
$msg_to_user = "";
if ($_POST['name'] != "") {

    require_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");

    // Be sure to filter this data to deter SQL injection, filter before querying database
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM newsletter WHERE email='$email'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand);
    $numRows = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
        if (!$email) {

        $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">Please type an email address ' . $name . '.</font></h4>';
    } else if ($numRows > 0) {
        $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="FF0000">' . $email . ' is already in the system.</font></h4>';

    } else {
        $sqlCommand="INSERT INTO newsletter (name, email, dateTime)                                                     VALUES(?,?,NOW() )";
$stmt= $myConnection->prepare($sqlCommand);
$stmt=->bind_param('ss',$name,$email);
$stmt->execute();
    $msg_to_user = '<br /><br /><h4><font color="0066FF">Thanks ' . $name . ', you have been added successfully.</font></h4>';
        $name = "";
        $email = "";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this code:

```
$stmt=->bind_param('ss',$name,$email);
```

It should be this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$name,$email);
```

---

Further (unrelated) advice:

- Fix your SQL injection vulnerabilities by using parameterized queries. See [*How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- Correctly and consistently indent your code to prevent unreadability.

Comment: thanks, always miss little thing...tire job to try to code whole day long >.<